# gofpdf - bold text between center aligned text

Tags: go, pdf-generation

I wanted to render text between center aligned text.
This is what I tried

```golang
html := pdf.HTMLBasicNew()
_, lineHt := pdf.GetFontSize()
html.Write(lineHt, "<center>My name is <b>Bot<b></center>")
```

but only `My name is` is aligned to center instead of whole text `My name is Bot`

How can I achieve this with [gofpdf](https://github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf)
or any other package in go to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I created a simple program for pdf generation and inserted your code snippet into it , but I did not face the any issue ,whole text `My name is Bot` is aligned to center.Below is the code I have written:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf"
)

func main() {
    pdf := gofpdf.New("P", "mm", "A4", "")
    pdf.AddPage()
    pdf.SetFont("Courier", "", 16)

    html := pdf.HTMLBasicNew()
    _, lineHt := pdf.GetFontSize()
    html.Write(lineHt, "<center>My name is <b>Bot<b></center>")
    err := pdf.OutputFileAndClose("myFile2.pdf")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```